# jQuery create element and use it

Tags: jquery, append

For example, I have something like:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <button class="button">Click</button>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.button').click(function() {
            $('#buttons').append('<button class="button">Click</button>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I press "Click" button, the script will create a new button with the same class "button". 
When I press this new button -- nothing happens.

I understand why, but I don't know how to avoid this.
I want my script "see" just created button.

Comment: Did you [search first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084293/how-to-make-live-click-event-on-new-added-dom/10084329#10084329)?

Comment: Yes, i did search, but i didn't found the answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) to bind to delegated events

```
$("#buttons").on("click", ".button", function () {
   $('#buttons').append('<button class="button">Click</button>');    
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/66H8W/

Comment: You are my saver. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Hiya **demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/vcrF3/ **or http://jsfiddle.net/vcrF3/1/

http://api.jquery.com/on/ **quote**

> events-mapA map in which the string keys represent one or more
>   space-separated event types and optional namespaces, and the values
>   represent a handler function to be called for the event(s).

**Jquery code**

```
   $.fn.ready(function() {
       $('div').on("click", ".button",  function() {
           $('#buttons').append('<button class="button">Click</button>');
          // alert('append button is clicked');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Read http://api.jquery.com/on/, paying particular attention to the "direct and delegated events" section.